# Call click event on last clicked row in YUI datatable

Tags: javascript, dom-events, yui, yui-datatable

I have a YUI datatable and I have a function which is invoked when I click on a row:

```
...
YAHOO.keycoes.myDatatable = myDatatable;
...
myDatatable.subscribe("rowClickEvent", oneventclickrow);
var oneventclickrow = function( args ) {
    ...
}
```

I'd like to invoke the function subscribed to `rowClickEvent` on the row which is currently highlighted in the datatable (the row which was clicked for the last time).

I've tried to do something like this:

```
YAHOO.keycoes.myDatatable.getSelectedRows()[0].rowClickEvent()
```

but `getSelectedRows()` doesn't return any row. How can I get the highlighted row in the datatable and then call the function associated with `rowClickEvent`?

Comment: Javi -- There's a dedicated forum for YUI DataTable discusion -- http://yuilibrary.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=90 -- if you don't get a great answer here on SO, you may want to try over there.  -Eric

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://jsbin.com/ideha) goes a powerful application when i show YUI datatable funcionality. See its source code To get a good insight how i use YUI datatable.

I use a helper like

```
var datatableUtils = {
    getSelected:function(datatable) {
        var records = datatable.getRecordSet().getRecords();

        for(var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
            if(datatable.isSelected(records[i])) {
                return records[i];
            }
        }

        return null;
    },
    removeAll:function(datatable) {
        var records = datatable.getRecordSet().getRecords();

        for(var i = (records.length - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
            datatable.deleteRow(records[i]);
        }
    },
    removeSelected:function(datatable) {
        datatable.deleteRow(datatableUtils.getSelected(datatable));
    },
    selectAll:function(datatable) {
        var records = datatable.getRecordSet().getRecords();

        for(var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
            datatable.selectRow(records[i]);
        }
    }
};
```

And when i want to subscribe some event, i do as follows

```
datatable.user.subscribe("rowClickEvent", function(args) {
  /**
    * Keep in mind this keyword refers To YUI datatable instance 
    *
    * args.target allows yui get row clicked
    */

     if(this.isSelected(args.target)) {
         alert("row selected");
     }
}
```

I hope It can be useful